# DC to DC converter connection

Tags: dc-dc-converter, negative-voltage

I am fairly new to electronics and I started to have some doubts. I am going to use a DC to DC converter R1SE-0505/H2-R (5V to 5V) to have an isolated power supply for the audio components. I have just realized that in the datasheet connection schema there is a negative voltage supply needed to connect to this converter. Is it safe and will it still work properly if I connect the ground to the negative voltage input pin?

Comment: ‘Ground’ is a nebulous term. If you mean it as your 0V reference point, then you really have little choice as to whether you connect the  -input of the dc/dc converter to it. The dc/dc converter expects 5V in, so you must give it that.  For audio, you would normally follow the output of the dc/dc converter with a linear regulator to eliminate the noise of the dc/dc converter. The datasheet says it can output up to 0.1V of noise. Then you have the common mode noise as well. You might be making things worse rather than better for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converter does not need negative input voltages.

The converter takes 5V in.

If you have 5V difference, e.g. 5V for the positive terminal and 0V for the negative terninal then that is enough.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Yes, it can be confusing. It doesn't need - 5 volts on pin 1 - regard pin 1 as the return connection for the incoming 5 volts that you power the device with.

It's a similar story for the output; the 5 volt output version puts out 5 volts between +Vout and -Vout.